# Continue Shopping redirect to previous category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating an e-commerce website using Woocommerce and I need some help with a redirect. So the layout is images of Category 1 Category 2 etc.

When Category 1 is clicked on, it opens  category 1a category 1b etc when category 1a is clicked, it opens up list of products.

If user is on page 3 of of category 1a and clicks on product. it goes to single product page and when they click add to cart. It now goes to the cart page and offers an option to continue shopping. When the user clicks continue shopping, I want it to go back to category1a page 3 or if easier , the specific category the user was in.

With the code below, I managed to redirect it to the main shop page but the client is requesting to go to where the user was prior to clicking on product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_message', 'woocommrece_custom_add_to_cart_message' );
```

function woocommrece_custom_add_to_cart_message() {

```
global $woocommerce;
```

// Output success messages

```
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {

    $return_to = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); // Give the url, you want to redirect which would be previous location before user clicked on product
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'More Donation Options &rarr;', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'Donation successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ) );
} else {

    $message = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a> %s', get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ), __( 'View Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'added to cart.', 'woocommerce' ) );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for primary category... add to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_message( $message, $product_id) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    $return_to = get_term_link( $terms[0], 'product_cat');
    $message    = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping?', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'Your cart was updated.', 'woocommerce' )  );
return $message;
}
```